# Vim: error opening files <SNR>62_InitializePythonBuiltin the Python's site module could not be loaded

Tags: bash

I have set up vim on a new machine according to [Vimlander-2-The-Quickening](https://github.com/spicycode/Vimlander-2-The-Quickening), but I keep running into the following errors when I open a file in command mode: `:e /path/to/file`, `:vs /path/to/file`, or `:sp /path/to/file`. Does anyone recognize these errors or resolved them?

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>62_UseConfigFiles[26]..<SNR>62_Initialize[47]..<SNR>62_InitializePythonBuiltin:
line   23:
E887: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python's site module could not be loaded.
Error detected while processing function <SNR>62_UseConfigFiles[41]..<SNR>62_UseConfigFiles_Python_Builtin:
line    6:
E887: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python's site module could not be loaded.
I suspect there is something wrong with my shell config, but it's hard to identity the cause of the problem.
```

I suspect there is something wrong with my shell config and how it loads Python, but it's hard to identity the cause of the problem.

Comment: it is a bug in one of your plugins, number 62 in the output of `:scriptnames` and possibly also to your python config.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt do you mean, /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1400_1/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim ?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt is there a plugin I can comment out in my vim setup that can help me avoid this?

Comment: the spellfile plugin does not have a function called **InitializePythonBuiltin", at least not my version at $VIMRUNTIME/plugin/spellfile.vim. Are you sure, you checked Number 62 in the output of `:scriptnames`